# CSS3 Selector Problem

Tags: css, checkbox, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I can`t find out why this workes:

```
input[ type = "text" ]:last-of-type:focus{ border:1px solid red; }
```

but this doesn`t work:

```
input[ type = "checkbox" ]:last-of-type:checked{ border:1px solid red; }
```

The "border" property is just an example, any other properties is also, dismissed!

Comment: What browsers have you tested this with? Have you checked that you can set a border on checkbox in that browser in the first place? What does your markup look like?

Comment: Mozilla Firefox, IE, Chrome, Safari, Opera; this is just an example, man!
You can test any property, not only border! No property is done through the second code!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Testing</title>
<style>
input[ type = "checkbox" ]:last-of-type:checked{ top: 100px;  }
input[type='checkbox'] { position: absolute; top: 200px; }
</style>
<h1>Testing</h1>
<form>
        <input type="submit" />
        <input type="checkbox" />
</form>
```

It works perfectly in Chrome for me. Presumably you didn't try it with any properties that are respected on checkboxes in the browsers you were testing in.

Comment: It`s better to change my question, why the third line on "Style" does not work:
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Testing</title>
<style>
input[ type = "checkbox" ]{display:none}
input[ type = "checkbox" ]:last-of-type:checked + label{color:red; }
input[ type = "checkbox" ]:last-of-type:checked ~ p{color:red; }
</style>
<form>
    
        <input type="checkbox" id="c1" /><label for="c1">Check1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" /><label for="c2">Check2</label>
        <p>Hello!</p>


</form>

Comment: You mean, you see the <p> tag in red, by clicking the second label?!!

Comment: @BiJO0L,ok, that works in firefox, but not chrome... I added a checked to the second checkbox before, so chrome uses the initial checked value to determine the style of the p tag but doesn't update it on changes to the state of the checkbox. Sounds like a bug to report.