# Styling checkboxes and radiobuttons

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $("form :input").css("border", "3px solid red");
    });
</script>

    <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/>Widgets
    <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" />Views    
    <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" />Contents
    <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" checked="checked" />Services

 Gender:<input id="Radiobox1" type="radio" />M<input id="F" type="radio" />F <br /> <br /> <br />
```

No style is applied to the checkboxes and radiobuttons... why?

Comment: this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css. "his is one of those outstanding form elements that browsers tend not to let you style that much"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the problem is unrelated with jQuery. Browsers won't allow css customization on such elements.

Check [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css).

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is giving all input elements inside a form a 3 pixel red border. You don't have a form so it won't do anything.

You can do this all in css instead. If you stick the following in your head, it should work:

```
<style type="text/css">
input { border: 3px solid red; }
</style>
```

As TonioElGringo said, it looks like it won't do anything anyway, but I'm guessing you're putting a border on as a placeholder (to prove the javascript works) for something prettier?

Comment: You're quite right about his jQuery selector, but unfortunately radio, and checkbox, inputs can't be styled: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/6c6W5/).

Comment: What you could do (but isn't universally supported or EXACTLY the same as a border) is to use outline instead of border