# Css to darken checkbox

Tags: html, css

I have an application that prints html files, the quailty looks good when printed from IE. However I've noticed when printing from FireFox the checkbox's look very light. It's almost difficult to tell if the box is checked or not. Is there a easy way to darken these checkboxes

Answer (score 2):

As it's Firefox you are talking about, you probably could define a special print stylesheet like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css" />
```

And inside you could do:

```
input[type=checkbox] { background: #000000; }
```

However: Most browsers are configured to ignore background colors when printing. In addition to that form element rendering is usually up to the browser and by definition you can't really influence checkboxes.

Maybe you can find something useful in the related questions. For example here: [How to change checkbox's border style in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css)