# How can I style and animate a checkbox with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have an html checkbox input on my frontend interface.

All I want to know is, what is the best way to go about styling the standard tickbox into something nicer? Maybe a slider-switch?

I don't want individual browsers styling it how they want to.

Should I use pure jquery, or JQUI, or is there a good plugin?

There are plugins like this, that are a start, but I want to animate my tickbox.

http://damirfoy.com/iCheck/

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css) question. In other words, it's not really possible. But you can make something that acts like a checkbox using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good solution:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/10/15/animated-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-with-svg/

The article comes with source code as well as a in depth explanation. I know it's been forever since this question was asked but I thought I would relay this as it's been really helpful for me.