# Input type checkbox not working, chrome displays default

Tags: html, css

the input type checkbox just wont work, chrome displays the default checkboxes while my other css cases work and display how they should.

```
.checkbox{
border: 2px solid white !important;
background:#121f20 !important;
color:white !important;
font-family: open sans !important;
font-weight: 900 !important;
font-size: 15px !important;
padding:5px !important;    
}
```

html

```
<table class="tableEnd">
  <tr>
    <td class="emptyTd"> 

      <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" /> I certify that I have read and agreed to the General Terms and Agreement <br>
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="option" value="Check" > I certify that I have read and agreed to the Acceptable Use Policy       <br>

      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="option" value="Check"> I commission  to provision services immediately. Distance selling regulations do not apply<br></td>

  </tr> 
</table>

<table class="tableEnd">
  <tr> 
    <td class="coupon">Coupon <input type="text" name="coupon" value="code"> <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"></td>               
    <td class="payment" ><input class="button" type="submit" value="Order"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: i see no class `.checkbox` inside `<input type="checkbox">`

Comment: Checkboxes aren't easy to style, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css

Comment: @MelanciaUK you'd use `input[type="checkbox"] { }`, not `checkbox { }`.

Comment: Besides, `font-family, font-weight, font-size` properties have no effect on checkboxes.

Comment: hi guys, i just did that, but its still not working as it should?

Comment: @HashemQolami good spot. Removed my comment. The OP added the classes anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to style the text beside the checkbox you should wrap it in a `label` alongside your checkbox:

```
<label>
    <input type="checkbox"  class="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" />
    I certify that I have read and agreed to the General Terms and Agreement
</label>
```

*Note how I've also removed the `br` element.*

You can then apply the styling to the `label` element itself:

```css
label {
    border: 2px solid white;
    background:#121f20;
    color:white;
    display: block; /* Achieves the same effect of the now-removed br element. */
    font-family: open sans;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding:5px; 
}
```

If you're wanting to style the actual checkbox then you'll need to do some research into how to best achieve this, as most browsers do not apply any CSS to checkbox inputs. See: [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score 1):

Checkbox does not support border and padding, thats why we use customize checkboxes useing javascript/jquery plugins.

There are lots of plugins available e.g. http://www.sitepoint.com/15-jquery-radio-button-checkbox-style-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

None of the properties you are changing have any effect on checkboxes in Chrome.

They have no text, so `font-family`, `font-weight` and `font-size` are nonsense.

Some browsers (although I don't recall seeing one in a long time) support styling the `border`, `background`, `color` and `padding` of checkboxes, but Chrome does not.

People wanting to style them usually use hack involving hiding the checkbox itself and changing the appearance of the associated `<label>` element.