# -moz-appearance notwork properly in radio button

Tags: html, css, webkit, mozilla

I have this dropdown with radio button:

[image]

And when is clicked my dropdown change to this:

[image]

but in mozilla don´t change is like not style have:

[image]

My css is this(only put one style be cause is the same for the rest of element);

when is clicked the dropdown:

```
li:first-child input[type='radio']{
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    border:3px solid #6a706d;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    /*box-shadow:0 0 5px 0px #6a706d inset;*/
    }
```

and this is when appear in the dropdown:

```
.status-1{
       -webkit-appearance:none;
       -moz-appearance: none;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    border:3px solid #6a706d;
    border-radius:50%;
    outline:none;
    margin: 0 13px -3px 0;
    }
```

Here is mi [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/muuu8758/)

Comment: Share your code by fiddle please....

Comment: i post my fiddle, thx for u support!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allright, i got it. This is not a element that you can change with firefox. The only way to do this, is to fake it like this:
[Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/muuu8758/7/)

There have been previous questions on stackoverflow about this. Check [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css)

Comment: Thanks, and Im sorry i just look like moz appareance none but not like the title of the link, the code work, i just need change the posicion of the new color cause is outside of the original radio