# how to do colored checkbox in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, checkbox

This is a page code that shows attendance report of student.I want checkbox in colored if checked green else red.please help me to do this.I tried it but didn't work.Now i can click only on one checkbox that change color.check this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JgICk.png

```
<style>
.checkbox {
  margin: 0 0 2em 2em;
}
.checkbox .tag {
  color: #595959;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  width: 120px;
}
.checkbox label {
  display: inline;
}
.checkbox .input {
  display: none;
}
.input + label {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid #cacece;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  padding: 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.input:checked + label:after {
  background-color: green;
  color: #595959;
  content: '\2714';
  font-size: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 2px 8px 2px 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
}
</style>
 <?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    //Here goes array
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['student']);$i++)
    {
        $name=$_POST['student'][$i];
        echo $name;
    }
}
?>

</head>
<body >
Report Attendance
<form name="myform" action="" method="post">
<div class="checkbox">
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" summary="">
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){?>
<tr><td> <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="input"  name="student[]" value="<?php echo $row['stu_id']; ?>" checked="checked"   > <?php echo $row['stu_name'] ; ?> <label for="input"></label>
<br/></td></tr>
<?php }?>

</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `id` must be unique within a document ... you have multiple inputs with `id="input"` - not sure that's the problem though, but it WILL cause problems somewhere for sure

Comment: can i use array as id??

Comment: no - but as I said, I don't think that's your issue

Comment: okay........................... :(

Comment: what may be useful is to see the actual page source (not the PHP) - i.e. what the browser actually gets - easier for others to debug it for you

Comment: you can't style the checkboxes, i doubt anything can happen in any browser ... you need to use images or font awesome to simulate the pucture you posted. - > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css

Comment: @SibyXavier my comment above is still valid but i didnt see you are already working around this and inputs are hidden, +1 for the interesting example

Comment: There are [accessible checkbox and radios](http://filamentgroup.github.io/checkboxradio/) which provide a very good basis and are easily styled. Beware about using only red and green color to indicate true/false: 10% of european/north american men (caucasian?) are red/green color blind. There are many other color blindness but red/green is by far the most prominent one. You should convey information also with another mean (text, symbol, etc), not only with color.

Comment: @FelipeAls Thankyou for your valuable information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make id as unique and labels should point to unique id. Here is the jsfiddle with static HTML https://jsfiddle.net/sua2wsm1/

below changes required in your HTML page

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" summary="">
<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){?>
<tr><td> <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="input<?php echo $row['stu_id']; ?>"  name="student[]" value="<?php echo $row['stu_id']; ?>" checked="checked"   > <?php echo $row['stu_name'] ; ?> <label for="input<?php echo $row['stu_id']; ?>"></label>
<br/></td></tr>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, duplicates ID can be the problem. A label is link to an input with the `for` attribute. So, if you click on the label, it'll be the same as clicking on the input. Your css is hiding the inputs, and using `label:after` as a box. So, if all inputs have the same id, clicking on a label will not work as expected