# How to apply my class from css to checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this working code but why the checkbox is not affecting it?.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#txt2").val() == 2) {
    alert("Hello");
    $("#txt").removeClass('validation');
    $("#chk").removeClass('validation');
  } else {
    $("#txt").addClass('validation');
    $("#chk").addClass('validation');
  }
});
```

```css
.validation {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
    <input type="text" id="txt">
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
```

Anyone know about this issue or problem?.

Comment: @Tushar yes if i click my button not meet the condition that i set

Comment: You can use `$('#txt, #chk').toggleClass('validation', $('#txt').val() === '2');` instead of `if...else`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your checkbox *is* getting the class (you can tell in the DOM inspector); you don't see the styling because the checkbox border isn't shown.

Some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css) suggests using `outline` rather than `border` for checkboxes; see the new style rule in the example below.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#txt2").val() == 2) {
    alert("Hello");
    $("#txt").removeClass('validation');
    $("#chk").removeClass('validation');
  } else {
    $("#txt").addClass('validation');
    $("#chk").addClass('validation');
  }
});
```

```css
.validation {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background-color: #ffeeee;
}
input[type=checkbox].validation {
  outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
    <input type="text" id="txt">
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#txt2").val() == 2) {
    alert("Hello");
    $("#txt").removeClass('validation');
    $("#chk").removeClass('border');
  } else {
    $("#txt").addClass('validation');
    $("#chk").addClass('border');
  }
});
```

```css
.validation {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background-color: #ffeeee;
}
.border {
  outline: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
    <input type="text" id="txt">
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
```

1. Use outline

Answer (score 1):

Acutally your checkbox *is* getting the class. Use your browser inspector to see it.
The `background-color` alone has not effect on the checkbox.

To show you I change the cursor. Put your mouse on the checkbox then click on the button and put your mouse on it again.

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
  if ($("#txt2").val() == 2) {
    alert("Hello");
    $("#txt").removeClass('validation');
    $("#chk").removeClass('validation');
  } else {
    $("#txt").addClass('validation');
    $("#chk").addClass('validation');
  }
});
```

```css
.validation {
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background-color: #ffeeee;
  cursor: wait;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
    <input type="text" id="txt">
  </td>
</tr>
<input type="text" id="txt2">
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Click">
```