# CSS: style radio button with label next to it?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style a radio button and place a label inline with the radio button using CSS.

But the radio button doesn't look right and its label is not inline with it.

I need to achieve this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STAkA.png)

This is what I have so far:

```css
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
 border-radius:50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
    background: #000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
 border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="M">
<label for="male">Male</label>

<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="F">
<label for="female">Female</label>
```

EDIT:

I need the all the radio buttons and their labels all in one line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with radio button styling when checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48459433/issue-with-radio-button-styling-when-checked)

Comment: `overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 0;` to label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're open to some HTML adjustments you might find this more flexible:

Make sure to include a `focus` state for the input to ensure it is accessible for keyboard users.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

span:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: black;
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked~span:after {
  display: block;
}

input[type="radio"]:focus~span {
  outline: 2px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<label for="male">Male
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="M">
   <span></span>
</label>


<label for="female">Female
  <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="F">
   <span></span>
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can before at the label, so it will look like the image

```css
input{
  display: none;
}

label{
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px
}

label span{
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
     -moz-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
     -moz-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

input:checked + label span:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 8px;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #222;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="M"/>
<label for="male"><span></span>Male</label>

<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="F"/>
<label for="female"><span></span>Female</label>
```

Comment: The inner black circle in your example is not centered. its placed on the top right?

Comment: It is centered, http://prntscr.com/i8nh9t which browser are you using? I didn't add the hack prefix to display flex, it may be not working in your browser

Comment: its not centered. I use chrome. The black dot is way off the center. https://prnt.sc/i8qtks

Comment: that's weird, you may be using an old version

Comment: there's an alternative instead of using display flex in `label span` you can set `position: relative` and then in the before you set `top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` here is a fiddle, try it: https://jsfiddle.net/5goh2aee/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your label both for displaying the actual radio button and for the actual label, you will indeed run into a problem :
Right now, you tell you `<label>` to be a circle 20px width, and to at the same time contain your text.
Try with this, instead :

```
input[type="radio"] + label::before
{
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    border-radius:50%;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

This adds a pseudo-element to your label, which you can style as you would any `<div>` or `<span>`.
Also, for you checked radio button, I would simplify :

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before
{
    background: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `::before` to the `input + label`.

```css
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label::before
{
    content:'';
    background: #fff;
    border: solid 2px #000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   border-radius:50%;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label::before
{
    background: #000;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="M">
<label for="male">Male</label>

<input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="F">
<label for="female">Female</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 35px;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.container input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 25px;
    width: 25px;
    background-color: #eee;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #2196F3;
}
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}
.checkmark:after {
  top: 9px;
 left: 9px;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: white;
}
```

```html
<label class="container">One
  <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container">Two
  <input type="radio" name="radio">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Hope this helps.... :)