# how to change input [type="checkbox"] border color

Tags: html, css

```
.contests input[type="checkbox"]{
   background: #fff;
   margin-right: 10px;
   border: 1px solid #fff;
   width: 1rem;
}
```

```
.contests input[type="checkbox"]{
    background: #fff;
    margin-right: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 1rem;
}
```

I want to change the border color checkbox how can I change this

Comment: border: 1px solid #fff > replace #fff to the color you want

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460501/how-to-change-checkboxs-border-style-in-css

Comment: Please have a look at this answer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css

Comment: form elements ( like checkox, radio, select etc. )  are rendered by each browser differently. It's hard to style them ( sometimes impossible ) . If you want to have full control over the element then I suggest you use something else ( eg. a `span` ) , hide the checkbox elem inside a `label`  and style the span using the `checked` prop on the checkbox. ( eg `input[type='checkbox']:checked + ( or ~ )  span { add checked styles } `

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Answer (score -1):

you have to use outline styles like this

```
.contests input[type="checkbox"]{
     outline-style: solid;
     outline-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Title of the document</title>
    <style>
        .form-group input {
        padding: 0;
        height: initial;
        width: initial;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        display: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        .form-group label {
        position: relative;
        cursor: pointer;
        }
        .form-group label: before {
        content:'';
        -WebKit-appearance: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        border: 2px solid #0079bf;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), inset 0px -15px 10px -12px 
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
        padding: 10px;
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        vertical-align: middle;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-right: 5px;
        }
        .form-group input:checked + label:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        left: 9px;
        width: 6px;
        height: 14px;
        border: solid #0079bf;
        border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
        transform: rotate(45deg);
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="new">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="checkbox" id="html">
            <label for="html">HTML</label>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```